# No sound issue in Zorin OS 16.2

Tags: audio, alsa, pulse-audio, zorin

I've installed Zorin OS to try it out because it's based on Ubuntu and I like the interface and other things in it but I have a problem. My sound card is recognized by Alsa and activated but I have no sound, I don't know why... I've followed some tuto to fix this kind of problem but nothing works...
My PC is a Samsung galaxy book pro 2 360 if you need to check the hardware. 
In the tuto of sound troubleshooting of Ubuntu, they made me create a link to the Alsa config so I give it to you some of the content of it.

```
!!Linux Distribution
!!------------------

ID_LIKE=ubuntu UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal


!!DMI Information
!!---------------

Manufacturer:      SAMSUNG ELECTRONICS CO., LTD.
Product Name:      950QED
Product Version:   P10AKK
Firmware Version:  P10AKK.730.230203.SH
System SKU:        SCAI-ICPS-A5A5-ADLP-PAKK
Board Vendor:      SAMSUNG ELECTRONICS CO., LTD.
Board Name:        NP950QED-KA1FR

!!ALSA Version
!!------------

Driver version:     k5.15.0-71-generic
Library version:    
Utilities version:  1.2.2


!!Loaded ALSA modules
!!-------------------

snd_hda_intel (card 0)


!!Sound Servers on this system
!!----------------------------

PipeWire:
      Installed - Yes (/usr/bin/pipewire)
      Running - Yes

Pulseaudio:
      Installed - Yes (/usr/bin/pulseaudio)
      Running - Yes


!!Soundcards recognised by ALSA
!!-----------------------------

 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0x601d190000 irq 174


!!PCI Soundcards installed in the system
!!--------------------------------------

00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller [0401]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:51c8] (rev 01)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Sound
```

I hope someone have an idea of how to fix it  
If you need anything else to help me debug let me know!

In order to answer to the comment of @Destroy666 here is some screenshots of the command I did to check the audio config:

`alsamixer`:

[image: alsamixer]

`lshw -class multimedia`

[image: lshw -class multimedia]

`pactl info`:

[image: pactl info]

Sound card error grep filtering:

[image: Sound card]

Comment: Maybe https://unix.stackexchange.com/ is more appropriate?

Comment: Hello, please include any sort of scripts/configs as code here, so that it's not lost if that website goes down. That one is quite long so shortening it to show only relevant parts would also be welcome.

Comment: @Destroy666 I just update the post, is it okay or you need something else?

Comment: I think you didn't fully understand. The effect should be that there won't be a link to an external website with lots of script/config text, otherwise your question is likely to be downvoted/buried.